# How to check the sdp plan (plan-b or unified-plan) used in RTCPeerConnection object in Safari (and all browsers)?

Tags: webrtc

How to check the sdp plan (plan-b or unified-plan) used in RTCPeerConnection object?

I know in Chrome I can call:

```
var p = new RTCPeerConnection()
console.log('plan:', p.getConfiguration().sdpSemantics)
```

The `sdpSemantics` works on Chrome, but does not have on Safari, how to check that on Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my research, it looks like there is no simple solution for this to be sure.

However, according to the docs, we can differentiate `Plan-b` / `unified-plan` by how the SDP looks like when there is more than 1 track of one kind.

In the unified plan, every track of the same kind has a separate `m=` section in the SDP, while in `Plan-B` they are grouped together.

Here is the working code snippet:

```
function isUnifiedPlanEnabled() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const track = canvas.captureStream(1).getTracks()[0];
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
    pc.addTrack(track);
    pc.addTrack(track.clone());

    return pc.createOffer().then(offer => {
        const sdpRows = offer.sdp.split('\n')
        const mVideoRows = sdpRows.filter(row => row.indexOf('m=video') === 0)

        return mVideoRows.length === 2
    })
}
```